# How does one programmatically add a logon/logoff/startup/shutdown script to a GPO via c#?

Tags: c#, scripting, authentication, logoff, gpo

So I've been able to make use of the GPMC library to add GPO's and link them to OU's.  However my program needs to be able to attach logon/logoff/etc scripts to the GPO User/Computer configuration.  I could go and edit the scripts.ini file and then proceed to edit the gpt.ini file version, but this seems @$$ backwards to be doing it that way.  Is there something I'm missing in the GPMC library that I can utilize to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: For those looking at this, and since there has been no reply, I ended up using GPMC's backup/restore feature and modifying the scripts.ini file.

Comment: Now you've got me curious. Why would you need to increment the gpt.ini file version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a direct way, but I was able to use GPMC's backup/restore/import feature to help set up the GPO to the point where I was able to just edit the scripts.ini file.